# How to control the font size of the entries of TOC in KOMA-Script

Tags: latex

I used the command `\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}` to add the *subsubsection* to TOC. But the font size of *subsubsection* is larger than that of *section* and *subsection* (Please refer the attached image). Can someone please help me to set the font size of *subsubsection* in TOC same as the font size of *section* and *subsection*?

[image]

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]?

Comment: Thank you for asking me to post MWE. I was able to figure out why this is the case while I was working on MWE. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great to her that you've been able to solve your problem. Could you please write up a short answer to make sure that other users with the same problem will be able to participate in what you learned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the MWE that also includes solution to my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}


\usepackage{babel}                
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.4}               
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\sffamily}   % I added this line of code. This solved my problem
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{4.1}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-1cm}}

\begin{document}

    \pagestyle{plain}
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \vspace*{-2cm} 
    \tableofcontents
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

     \chapter{This is Chapter 1}
      \section{This is section 1}
       \subsection{This is subsection 1}
        \subsubsection{This is subsubsection 1}

\end{document}
```